# Need to slice the string in java and then JSON.parse it

Tags: java, json

Hi I have a long string with three parameters with separator ("|"). How can I slice it back in java and then JSON.parse one of the parameters.

Please help.

Comment: For starters, this isn't Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string with

```
String [] parameters = l_sReprocessData.split("\\|");

for (String param : parameters) {
    String newParam = param;
}
```

I don't understand what you want to do with JSON and the parameter. Something like this?

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("{\"parameter\":\"" + parameter[1] + "\"}");
```

Comment: I want to split the l_sReprocessData and then after I have all the three parameters I want to JSON.parse the l_sProcessedImage because this was json.stringified so to get the original object  back from string I need to use this. I dont know how can I separate the three parameters and retrieve them .

Comment: As i said, use the split method to separate the 3 parameters. If you want to convert JSON to String, use String param = JSONObject.getString("param"); You have to know the name of the field in the JSON.

Comment: no i have to convert it back to object. Its string already . and how to get the 3 parameters after split( as in get them in different variables) ??

Comment: The String array gets all parameters as you can see. You just access each element and copy them to other variables. You either want to convert JSON to Java object, or Java object to JSON, and both of those i have showed examples

Comment: yes i got this but how can I access them ?
String firstParameter = parameters [0] ??

Answer (score 0):

Split uses regex and the pipe character `"|"` has special significance in regex, so to split on a literal pipe, you must escape it:

One way would be:

```
var l_cSeparator = "\\|";
```

---

In java:

```
String[] parts = input.split("\\|");
```

Comment: ok I will replace the separator with "\\|" but how to do slice in java , I have done it in js but have no clue with java and need to json.parse one parameter after slicing too.

Comment: I've added some java code. Regarding parsing JSON, that's a separate question - search for or ask a new new question